# A* Implementation for Snake to Follow Tail at Distance x

Tags: javascript, algorithm, a-star

I'm trying to code a snake AI in javascript and it's proving sort of challenging.
The a* Algorithm for the snake to find the food and then a way back to its tail was easy enough, but now I would like there to be a buffer between the snake head and its tail, so when the snake eats the food and the tail is right next to its head, it doesn't immediately follow the tail, but decides to take a detour to achieve a specified minimum distance away from its rear end, like so:

[image: fastest path]

[image: step 1]

[image: step 2]

[image: buffer path]

[image: step 1 and 2]

[image: step 3]

This creates a small breathing space between the snakes head and the snakes tail in case the food spawns in-between the two.

I can't seem to figure out how to adapt the a* algorithm to accommodate a buffer space. If you have the time, I would appreciate some pointers as to how I would go about implementing a "minimum follow distance" in a*.

Comment: One idea, make the actual tail 2 units longer but don't draw the last 2 units. That way those 2 spaces will be occupied by the invisible tail. (or some similar variation). Basically your a* needs to see spaces near the tail as not available so your check during a* would be `occupied = mapdata[mapcellY * mapwidth + mapcellX] || isNearTail(mapCellX, mapCellY)`

Comment: While this might be interesting and stave off a lot of bad situations, I'm not sure that it'll work in many cases once the snake's tail end gets "buried" in coils of its own tail or cut off by the edges of the grid. Are you trying to make a perfect AI or just something a bit better than a naive path to the apple?

Comment: @ggorlen I'm not quite sure what you mean, could you elaborate?. I'm trying to make an AI that solves snake perfectly in most cases, but also doesn't follow a precomputed hamilton cycle.

Comment: @gman I tried a similar approach and it ended up snagging at some point, I'll have to give it another go to see if I just did something wrong. I think you might be right though.

Comment: Well, clearly if if works as is, then if the only difference is the last N units of the tail are invisible you'd get your solution right? If you want other objects to be able to go into those cells then you might need some way to view them as occupied only when the head is using a*